# Asset upload fails on LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am currently trying to upload an asset to LinkedIn as per the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context#create-an-image-share.

I am requesting and granted the following permissions during signup:

`w_share%20rw_company_admin%20r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress`

But for some reason I am getting:

`Not enough permissions to access: POST-registerUpload /assets`

I'm pretty sure I do have permissions!! Its v2 of the LI API. Does anyone know what would be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else struggling with this - there is a NEW LI permission `w_member_social` which must be included even though it *isnt* listed within the APP permissions area.